# django- how two def in the same views.py pass the data

Tags: python, django, forms

In the same views.py, if I have 2 "def", how can I pass the data entry result in the 1st def to the 2nd def for filtering database?

Take an example:

```
def input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']

            return redirect('result')
       else:
            print form.errors
   else:
       form=InputForm()             
   return render_to_response('inputform.html',{'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))


class ResultView():
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

    # Here how can I get the form entry (name/age)from above def to filter the result?                    
    queryset=Result.filter(name=name,age=age)
    scor=Result.objects.filter(queryset)
    subject.Result.objects.filter(queryset)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        return context
```

**url**

```
url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
url(r'^input', 'result.views.input',name='input'),
```

In the above code, the queryset=Result.filter(name=name,...),here it cannot get the form data from the "def input". Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                age = form.cleaned_data['age']
                return Result.filter(name=name, age=age)
        return super(ResultView, self).get_queryset()
```

Comment: Thanks @EchoUA Team. if I want to keep the redirect function after submitting the form. how can I combine the redirect('result') with the return super(ResultView, self).get_queryset() that you put?

Comment: If You want redirect to Result with arguments "age" and "name" after validate form, You can use this scheme https://gist.github.com/anonymous/52918ccb37bc18d03e63

Comment: Just replace `{{DupontView.total_asset}}` on `{{ result.total_asset }}` and `{{DupontView.sales}}` on `{{ result.sales }}`

Comment: Hi @EchoUA Team, in your scheme, in "reverse('result')" part,you put different "?" and "&" in front of the field names, can I just use one (either & or ?) for all fields?

Comment: Hi @EchoUA Team, I updated the code as you suggest but some new issue occurs. Could you please help answer that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250458/django-1-8-error-nonetype-object-is-not-callable. Thanks a lot~