# django 1.8 error: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, database

Please see in picture, there is a form with 2 fields. After user entry the information and submit the form. The page will redirect to another html showing the form AND the filtered database result.

The structure of my project is 1 model with 2 classes(inputform; result), 2 html and 1 views.py.

The issue now is "'NoneType' object is not callable'. So I suspect it is because the views.py , there is something wrong. Your help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

**url**

```
from result.views import ResultView,InputFormView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,FormView,ListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
    url(r'^input/$',InputFormView.as_view(),name='input'), 
)
```

**views.py**

```
from result.forms import InputForm
from result.models import Result,Input
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic import FormView
....

@csrf_exempt

class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form = InputForm

    def get_success_url(self):  /*redirect to result page with submitted form information*/
        return ''.join(
            [
                reverse('dupont'),
                '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),
                '?region=',self.request.POST.get('region')
            ]
        )

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

/---Based on form entry, do the filter on the database-----/

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region,company=company)
                sales=Result.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('sales'))
                employee=Result.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('employee'))
                departments=Result.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('departments'))

                form.save()

                return render(request,'result_list.html',{'company':company},{'region':region},{'employee':employee},{'sales':sales},{'departments':departments})

            else:
                print form.errors
        else:
            form=InputForm()                   
        return super(ResultView,self).get_queryset()
```

Traceback:

```
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
205.         form = self.get_form()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
74.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
Exception Type: TypeError at /input/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

result_list.html

```
<div class="basicinfo">         <!--Entry Form information submitted by user-->

    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Company</td>
        <td>{{ company }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Region</td>
        <td>{{ region }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
{% endfor %}
</div>     

<!--Showing the filtered result in database-->  
<td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<tr><b>Sales</b></tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{sales}}</td>

</tr>
<tr><b>Employee</b></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{employee.employee__sum}}</td>

</tr>
<tr><b>Departments</b></tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{departments.departments__sum}}</td>
</td></table>
```

input.html

```
<div class="field">
        {{ form.company.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Company:</label>
        {{ form.company }}
</div>

<div class="field" >
<label> Select the Region:
    {{ form.region }}
        {% for region in form.region.choices %}
        <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
        {% endfor %}
</label>
</div>
```

Upgraded views.py based on suggestion

```
from result.forms import InputForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView,FormMixin
from django.contrib import messages
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.db.models import Sum,Avg
from django.views.generic.detail import MultipleObjectMixin

class InputFormView(FormMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form = InputForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form=self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
            print form.errors

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = DupontView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']

        queryset=Result.objects.filter(company=company,region=region)
        sales=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        employee=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('employee'))
        departments=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('departments'))

        return super(ResultView,self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dupont', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

class ResultView(MultipleObjectMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'


    <----how can I get the submitted information and query result here from InputFormView? Is following correct?--->

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object(queryset=Result.objects.filter(company=company,region=region))            
        return super(Result, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['InputFormView']= self.object
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.object. ? .all()  <---what to put here? are they  "sales","departments","employee" from database filtered result together with the form data-"region" and "company"?
```

Comment: could you please include the full traceback?

Comment: can you post result_list.html, seems like something fishy there !!

Comment: its not there, you gave a wrong link !! just post it here !

Comment: and what is dupont ? Why are you using it anyway ?

Comment: @miaomiao Two questions. 1) what are you doing which raises the "NoneType' object is not callable" error? Does it raise the error right after you submit the form? 2) Can you post the rest of the traceback (if there is more)? I want to know if the traceback point to a specific line of code.

Comment: hi@ojii, it should be "result" instead of "dupont", corrected in the snippet already. 1) it is showing "..not callable when go to page: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/input/" 2) it is the full traceback. thanks.

Comment: @miaomiao can you update your post to show your form on inputform.html? Let me know when you have done so (use '@user2719875' when replying so that I can get a notification when you are done - that way I can reply faster).

Comment: Hi @user2719875', I added "upgraded views based on suggestion" as per the suggestion by solarissmoke and pythad, but same error there, can you please help take a look~~looking forward to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a look at these files, maybe they will be helpful to you.
https://github.com/EchoUA/Tweaks-and-Hacks/tree/master/miaomiao

Comment: Hi @EchoUA Team,really thank you a lot and it is really helpful~~~,but this code still return the error of "XX missing a queryset" , as seen in the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251737/django-1-8-xview-is-missing-a-queryset-define-xview-model-xview-queryset, solarissmoke suggests that we shouldn't render template inside get_query method. I am still thinking how to make the code run.

Comment: Hi @EchoUA Team, also I have a doubt, why don't put the form.cleaned_data...these form handling code in "class InputFormView", instead of "class ResultView"?

Comment: could you please post the full traceback?

Comment: Hi @EchoUA Team, Please see the traceback in the following link's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251737/django-1-8-xview-is-missing-a-queryset-define-xview-model-xview-queryset

Comment: Hi @EchoUA Team, thank you a lot a lot~~ We have progess now, the input.html can show correctly now. But the result_list.html still returns the same error of "ResultView is missing a queryset..." with traceback shown in "stackoverflow.com/questions/33251737/…; I followed the doc:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#avoid-anything-more-complex to write the upgraded views.py but returns the same error as yours.

Comment: Please try to edit "ResultView" according to the example over [here](https://github.com/EchoUA/Tweaks-and-Hacks/blob/master/miaomiao/new_view.py). It should do the trick!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92956/discussion-between-miaomiao-and-echoua-team).

Answer (score 1):

in views.py, the context is one dictionary !

```
return render(request,'result_list.html',{'company':company,'region':region, 'employee':employee, 'sales':sales, 'departments':departments})


<div class="basicinfo">         <!--Entry Form information submitted by user-->

    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Company</td>
        <td>{{company}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Region</td>
        <td>{{region}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<!--Showing the filtered result in database-->  
<td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<tr><b>Sales</b></tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{sales}}</td>

</tr>
<tr><b>Employee</b></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{employee}}</td>

</tr>
<tr><b>Departments</b></tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{departments}}</td>
</td></table>
```

Comment: hi @Manjunath Satyamurthy, thanks a lot. Upgraded as what you suggest, there is error of "ResultView is missing a QuerySet. Define ResultView.model, ResultView.queryset, or override ResultView.get_queryset()."  Is there something else wrong in my views?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing way too much code for a simple form.

Create a simple form; which is just a search for your second view:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.CharField()
    region = forms.CharField()
```

Create a view to display the form:

```
def search_form(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']
        url = '{}?company={}&region={}'.format(reverse('result-list'), company, region)
        return redirect(url)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Create a view to display the results:

```
def show_results(request):
    company = request.GET.get('company')
    region = request.GET.get('region')
    if company is None or region is None:
        return redirect('input')

    # Your normal logic here
    queryset=Result.objects.filter(company=company,region=region)
    sales=Result.objects.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
    employee=Result.objects.aggregate(Sum('employee'))
    departments=Result.objects.aggregate(Sum('departments'))

    return render(request, 'results.html', {'sales': sales,
                                            'employee': employee,
                                            'departments': departments,
                                            'queryset': queryset})
```

Comment: Hi@Burhan Khalid,I like your simple code. But now after submitting the form, it could redirect to the result page. But it shows nothing in the form(submitted data) and table(filtered result). Is there anything wrong in my result_list.html posted above?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, when you send a GET request to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/input/
```

then you get the error. Do you get the same error when you send a post request to that URL? Try changing input.html to this:

```
<div class="field">
    <!-- Check if the errors exist first before calling them. 
         If youre sending a GET request, then form errors will 
         probably not exist. -->
        {% if form.company.errors %}
            {{ form.company.errors }}
            <label for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Company:</label>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form.company }}
</div>

<div class="field" >
<label> Select the Region:
    {{ form.region }}
        <!-- over here, are you sure form.region.choices exists? Can you
             post your model / model form so that we can verify that
             form.region.choices exists? -->
        {% for region in form.region.choices %}
        <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
        {% endfor %}
</label>
</div>
```

Let me know if you still get the error after using this code. In the code above, I left a comment mentioning to verify that form.region.choices exists. Can you upload your model and model form so that we can verify that form.region.choices exists?

Comment: hi@user2719875,thanks you a lot, your code works and the model does existe regarding to your note. I checked all the answers above, but there are all problems when redirecting to the result page that fail to show the form data. So I think I will learn ajax to see solve the issue.