# django 1.8：XView is missing a QuerySet. Define XView.model, XView.queryset,

Tags: python, django, database

I am getting error when go to the url: /result_list.html. But there is indeed queryset in the views.py, so what could be other reasons? Thanks in advance. The function is based on the form submitted by user, then filter the database and show the form entry and database result in the result_list.html.

**Traceback**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
159.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SCOR\result\views.py" in get_queryset
70.         return super(ResultView,self).get_queryset()
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get_queryset
    44. 'cls': self.**class**.**name**
    Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /result_list/
    Exception Value: ResultView is missing a QuerySet. Define ResultView.model, ResultView.queryset, or override ResultView.get_queryset().

Here below is the snippets:

**url**

```
from result.views import ResultView,InputFormView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,FormView,ListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
    url(r'^input/$',InputFormView.as_view(),name='input'), 
)
```

**views.py**

```
from result.forms import InputForm
from result.models import Result,Input
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic import FormView
....

@csrf_exempt

class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form = InputForm

    def get_success_url(self):  /*redirect to result page with submitted form information*/
        return ''.join(
            [
                reverse('dupont'),
                '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),
                '?region=',self.request.POST.get('region')
            ]
        )

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

/---Based on form entry, do the filter on the database-----/

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region,company=company)
                sales=Result.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('sales'))
                employee=Result.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('employee'))
                departments=Result.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('departments'))

                form.save()

                return render(request,'result_list.html',{'company':company},{'region':region},{'employee':employee},{'sales':sales},{'departments':departments})

            else:
                print form.errors
        else:
            form=InputForm()                   
        return super(ResultView,self).get_queryset()
```

**result_list.html**

```
<div class="basicinfo">         <!--Entry Form information submitted by user-->

    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Company</td>
        <td>{{company}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Region</td>
        <td>{{region}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<!--Showing the filtered result in database-->  
<td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<tr><b>Sales</b></tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{sales}}</td>

</tr>
<tr><b>Employee</b></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{employee}}</td>

</tr>
<tr><b>Departments</b></tr>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{departments}}</td>
</td></table>
```

**Version 2.0 views.py as per solarissmoke' and pythad's suggestion**

```
class InputFormView(FormMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form = InputForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form=self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
            print form.errors

    def form_valid(self, form):
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']

        return super(ResultView,self).form_valid(form) 《Q1:---If here to return to ResultView or InputFormView?--->

    def get_success_url(self):   #Redirect to result_list.html
        return reverse('result', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})


class ResultView(MultipleObjectMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

    <---Q2: How can I get the form data entry from InputFormView?-->

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = InputFormView.as_view()
        self.object = self.get_object(queryset=Result.objects.filter(company=company,region=region))            
        return super(Result, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['InputFormView']= self.object
        return context


    def get_queryset(self):

<--Error!-- this sentence is where reports error as "global name company,region not defined"-->

        queryset=Result.objects.filter(company=company,region=region)
        sales=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        employee=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('employee'))
        departments=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('departments'))

        return self.object.all()
```

Comment: Hi @pythad, because there are 2 html and 2 views, each reporting different errors, that's why I posted 2 questions here. Thank you a lot for your suggestion, can you take a look at my upgraded views.py? It returns same error after changing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You have an `if self.request.method == 'POST':` block in your `get_queryset` method. If that evaluates to `False` then you fall back to the parent `get_queryset` method, which is what triggers the error (because the parent method needs to be given either a model or a queryset, as indicated in the error). So if you try a simple GET request to `result_list/` it will fail because the `ListView` doesn't have a queryset.
2. You shouldn't be rendering templates from inside the `get_queryset` method. That method should return a queryset and nothing else. This will fail.
3. Your `ResultView` really shouldn't be handling the POSTed form data in the first place. You should be handling that in your `FormView` and then redirecting the user to the appropriate result view by using the `FormView`s `success_url` parameter as explained in the [documentation on form processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views).

Comment: Hi @solarissmoke, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I changed the views.py as per your suggestion, but there are still 1 question I don't understand. Could you please take a look at my "updated views.py as per your suggestion"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass the relevant arguments to your result view, and then perform the queryset logic in that view (and not in the form view).

Comment: Hi@solarissmoke, thanks. I uploaded the "Verson 2.0 views.py", but I got the error of "global name 'company' is not defined", so I suspect that the form entry data from InputFormView is not successfully pased to ResultView. I made notes in the snippet, could you please take a look? Thanks a lot.